# Unable to install scipy using pip after uninstall anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I used have anaconda on my Mac computer. I used rm -rf /anaconda to uninstall my anaconda, and then decided to install scipy using pip. I first download get-pip.py and run `python get.pip.py` and successfully installed pip. However, when I use `pip install scipy` to install scipy, got the following: `-bash: /anaconda/bin/pip: No such file or directory`. How could I solve it?

Comment: What's the output of `which pip`?

Comment: there is no output of which pip

Comment: You can try to use `full_path_to_python_install/Scrips/pip`, this should use the installed pip.

Comment: Restart your terminal, the terminal still thinks `~/anaconda/bin/pip` exists and hasn't refreshed.